# how to integrate : $\int_{x^2}^{x^3}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}$

Tags: definite-integrals

Need to compute:

$$\int_{x^2}^{x^3}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}$$

I tried to use partial fraction but got a messy algebra.

thanks.

Comment: Maybe there is something easier, but it looks nasty: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt%281+%2B+t%5E4%29

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want the *derivative* of this expression?

Comment: How did this integral arise?

Comment: well it's just an exercise. i dont want the derivative.

Comment: *Just an exercise*? That's an elliptic integral! Must be some advanced class you're taking.

Comment: @harald Henche-Olsen : can you show me how?

Comment: Sorry, I am no expert on elliptic integrals. I only know enough to recognize one when I see one.

Comment: look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200739/integral-int-01-sqrt1-x4dx

Comment: maybe @J.M. could help:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only interested in the cases of real number $x$ :

Case $1$: $x\geq1$

Then $\int_{x^2}^{x^3}\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}$

$=\int_{x^2}^{x^3}\dfrac{dt}{t^2\sqrt{1+\dfrac{1}{t^4}}}$

$=\int_{x^2}^{x^3}\dfrac{1}{t^2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!t^{-4n}}{4^n(n!)^2}dt$

$=\int_{x^2}^{x^3}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!t^{-4n-2}}{4^n(n!)^2}dt$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!t^{-4n-1}}{4^n(n!)^2(-4n-1)}\right]_{x^2}^{x^3}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(4n+1)x^{8n+2}}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(4n+1)x^{12n+3}}$

Case $2$: $-1\leq x\leq1$

Then $\int_{x^2}^{x^3}\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}$

$=\int_{x^2}^{x^3}\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!t^{4n}}{4^n(n!)^2}dt$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!t^{4n+1}}{4^n(n!)^2(4n+1)}\right]_{x^2}^{x^3}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!x^{12n+3}}{4^n(n!)^2(4n+1)}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!x^{8n+2}}{4^n(n!)^2(4n+1)}$

Case $3$: $x\leq-1$

Then $\int_{x^2}^{x^3}\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}$

$=-\int_{x^3}^{x^2}\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}$

$=-\int_{x^3}^{-1}\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}-\int_{-1}^1\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}-\int_1^{x^2}\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}$

$=\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!t^{-4n-1}}{4^n(n!)^2(-4n-1)}\right]_{x^3}^{-1}-\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!t^{4n+1}}{4^n(n!)^2(4n+1)}\right]_{-1}^1-\left[\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!t^{-4n-1}}{4^n(n!)^2(-4n-1)}\right]_1^{x^2}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!x^{-12n-3}}{4^n(n!)^2(4n+1)}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!(-1)^{-4n-1}}{4^n(n!)^2(4n+1)}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(4n+1)}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!(-1)^{4n+1}}{4^n(n!)^2(4n+1)}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!x^{-8n-2}}{4^n(n!)^2(4n+1)}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(4n+1)}$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(4n+1)x^{12n+3}}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2(4n+1)x^{8n+2}}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n(2n)!}{2^{2n-1}(n!)^2(4n+1)}$

Comment: is it elementary functions? because it should be an elliptical integral. how did you get the factorial part?

Comment: @abi: The factorial part comes from the taylor series expression of $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+t}}$ .

Answer (score 1):

For any $x \in [0,\infty]$, let $I(x)$ and $J(x)$ be the integrals
$$
I(x) = \int_0^x \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}
\quad\text{ and }\quad
J(x) = \int_{x^2}^{x^3} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}} = I(x^3) - I(x^2)
$$
Notice under the substitution $t = \frac{1}{u}$, 
$$\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}} = - \frac{du}{\sqrt{1+u^4}}$$
We find $I(x)$ and $J(x)$ satisfy following identities:

$$I(x) + I(\frac{1}{x}) = I(\infty)\quad\text{ and }\quad J(x) = -J(\frac{1}{x})$$
This means we only need to figure out what $I(x)$ is for $0 < x < 1$.

**Part 1 : As an Hypergeometric function**

For $|t| < 1$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}$ has an absolute convergence power series expansion. We can integrate the expansion term by term to get

$$I(x) = \int_0^x \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}
= \int_0^x \left[ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(\frac12)_k}{k!}(-t^4)^k\right] dt
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\frac12)_k}{k!}\frac{(-1)^k x^{4k+1}}{4k+1}
$$
where $(\gamma)_k = \gamma(\gamma+1)\cdots(\gamma+k-1)$ is the rising 
[Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol). Notice

$$\frac{(\gamma)_k}{(\gamma+1)_k} = \frac{\gamma(\gamma+1)\cdots(\gamma+k-1)}{(\gamma+1)(\gamma+2)\cdots(\gamma+k)} = \frac{\gamma}{\gamma+k}$$
We have $\frac{1}{4k+1} = \frac{(\frac14)_k}{(\frac54)_k}$ and $I(x)$ becomes

$$I(x) = x \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(\frac14)_k (\frac12)_k}{k!(\frac54)_k}(-x^4)^k$$
The expansion of the RHS is that for a 
[Hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) with
argument $-x^4$. More precisely,

$$\begin{cases}
I(x) &= x\cdot{}_2F_1( \frac14, \frac12; \frac54 ; -x^4)\\
J(x) &= I(x^3) - I(x^2) = x^3\cdot{}_2F_1( \frac14, \frac12; \frac54 ; -x^{12}) 
- x^2\cdot{}_2F_1( \frac14, \frac12; \frac54 ; -x^8)
\end{cases}$$

Even though it is sort of hard to extract analytic relations from hypergeometric functions,
there are highly efficient numeric routines around to evaluate them accurately. If what you
want is to evaluate it and get a number, this will be a good representation for $I(x)$ and hence $J(x)$.

On WolframAlpha, you can access the hypergeometric function though the function 
$\bf\text{HypergeometricPFQ}$ and evaluate $I(x)$ using the expression:

$$\bf x*\text{HypergeometricPFQ}[\{1/4,1/2\},\{5/4\},-x^4]$$

**Part 2: As an elliptic integral**

As pointed out by others, the integrals can be recasted as elliptical integrals.
Introduce variable $c$ and $s$ such that

$$t^2 = \frac12 \left(\frac{1}{c^2} - c^2\right)\quad\text{ and }\quad s = \sqrt{1-c^2}$$

We have $\quad\displaystyle \sqrt{1+t^4} = \sqrt{ 1 + \left(\frac12 \left(\frac{1}{c^2} - c^2\right)\right)^2 } = \frac12 \left(\frac{1}{c^2} + c^2\right).$

This implies
$\quad\displaystyle 2tdt = dt^2 = -\left(\frac{1}{c^3} + c\right) dc = -2\sqrt{1+t^4}\frac{dc}{c}$ and as a result,
$$\begin{align}
\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}} 
&= -\frac{dc}{tc} = -\frac{cdc}{tc^2} = \frac{sds}{tc^2}
= \frac{sds}{c\sqrt{\frac12\left(1-c^4\right)}} = \frac{ds}{c\sqrt{\frac12 (1+c^2)}}\\
& = \frac{ds}{\sqrt{(1-s^2)(1 - \frac12 s^2})}
\end{align}$$
Notice $s^2 = 1 - c^2 = 1 - \left(\frac12(\frac{1}{c^2} + c^2) -
\frac12(\frac{1}{c^2} - c^2)\right) = 1 + t^2 - \sqrt{1+t^4}$, we obtain
an alternate representation of $I(x)$:

$$I(x) = \int_0^x \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^4}} = F( \sqrt{1 + x^2 - \sqrt{1+x^4}} \;; \frac12 )$$

where $\quad\displaystyle F(y \;; m ) = \int_0^y \frac{ds}{\sqrt{(1-s^2)(1-ms^2)}}\quad$
is the Jacobi's form of [incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind). 
Please note that there is more than one form/convention of elliptic integrals. A lot of authors use the same term "incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind" for following integral:

$$F( \phi \mid m ) = \int_0^\phi  \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1-m\sin^2\theta}}
= \int_0^{\sin\phi} \frac{ds}{\sqrt{(1-s^2)(1-ms^2)}} = F( \sin\phi \;; m)
$$
On WolframAlpha, you can access the second form using the function $\bf \text{EllipticF}$ and 
evaluate $I(x)$ using the expression:

$$\bf \text{EllipticF}[ \text{ArcSin}[ \text{Sqrt}[1+x^2-\text{Sqrt}[1+x^4]] ], m ]$$