# How would I evaluate this integral?

Tags: integration

I have an integral
$$\int\sqrt{b^2-\frac{x^4}{a^4}} dx \quad a, b\in
\mathbb{R}$$

And I have no idea how to solve it. The $x^4$ term is stumping me. I've tried the standard $u$ and trig substitution methods but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+sqrt%281-x%5E4%29) reckons that you need an elliptic integral of the first kind.

Comment: Maybe it was originally a definite integral?

Comment: Correct it was originally a definite integral. Does the process change if this is the case?

Comment: Yes, the process may change. What are the limits of integration? (If you have those)

Comment: So the true values are $a=1.2,b=1.55$. I want to find the area bounded by this curve on the interval $(-1.494,1.494)$.

Comment: Are these numbers an approximation? under these variables there is a square root of a negative number. For example take x=1.49399<1.494 or just x=1.494 itself.

Comment: Yes, these are approximations of the calculated domain of the integrand.

Comment: In the case $\frac{c^4}{b^2a^4}=1$, this integral reduces, with the appropriate scalars due to change of variables, to this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200739/integral-int-01-sqrt1-x4dx

Comment: what is the region of integration?

Comment: I found the exact value of the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, with you numbers, the integration bounds are exactly
$$t_\pm=\pm \frac 3 5 \sqrt{\frac{31}{5}} \sim \pm 1.493987952$$ that is to say the limit of definition of the integrand.

$$I=\int\sqrt{b^2-\frac{x^4}{a^4}}\, dx$$

If you do not want to face nasty elliptic integrals, assuming $a>0$ and $b >0$, use
$$\sqrt{b^2-\frac{x^4}{a^4}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n a^{-4 n} b^{1-2 n} \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n}x^{4n}$$ to make after integration
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n}\frac {x^{4n+1}}{a^{4n}b^{2n-1}(4n+1) }$$

Now, for the integral
$$J=\int_{-a \sqrt{b} }^{+a \sqrt{b} }\sqrt{b^2-\frac{x^4}{a^4}}\, dx=2 a b^{3/2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n}}{4 n+1}$$
$$\color{blue}{J= a\, b^{\frac 32}\,\sqrt{\pi }\,\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)}}$$

More generally
$$K=\int_{-ka \sqrt{b} }^{+ka \sqrt{b} }\sqrt{b^2-\frac{x^4}{a^4}}\, dx=2 a b^{3/2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n}\frac{k^{4n+1}}{4 n+1}$$
$$\color{blue}{K=2\, k\, a\, b^{\frac 32}\,\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4};\frac{5}{4};k^4\right)}$$